# when installing @angular/cli in ubuntu error ocurred

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-56-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: run as sudo. try `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 4):

Try installing it using `--force` command

This worked for me:  `sudo npm install -g -f angular-cli`

Answer (score 1):

You have npm directory permission issue, please try with sudo.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

[Angularjs Installation guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation)

Answer (score 1):

you may try this below command:

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli